# TSQL Ploygon Transformation

Tags: t-sql, geojson

I'm new to using SQL server Geo-spatial functionality and I seem to have a formatting problem when I'm trying convert text to polygon.  I have all the county ploygons from the US Census and when I do a geojson validation check they are displaying correctly.  I tried to take those values and create tsql polyons but for some reason they are not valid. Here is what I have:

```
select geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((-95.388 42.909, -95.388 43.255, -94.913 43.255, -94.913 42.909, -95.388 42.909))', 4326);
```

The above should be a county in Iowa.  I have the following example from MS that is working:

```
select geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON((-122.358 47.653, -122.348 47.649, -122.348 47.658, -122.358 47.658, -122.358 47.653))', 4326);
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

For reference here is the geojson for the Iowa county:

{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "GEO_ID": "0500000US19041", "STATE": "19", "COUNTY": "041", "NAME": "Clay", "LSAD": "County", "CENSUSAREA": 567.238000 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -95.388182, 42.909897 ], [ -95.388078, 43.255221 ], [ -94.913723, 43.255054 ], [ -94.913890, 42.909700 ], [ -95.388182, 42.909897 ] ] ] } }